# PageView.builder move to the next page if based on a value from future (api)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `FutureBuilder` and inside is a `PageView.builder`. The `future` is calling an api and a list of flags is being fetched from the server. The flags are based on `'0'` & `'1'` like this `['1','1','0','0']`. What I want to do is to skip the pages from start that have flag '1'. In this case, page first should be the first `'0'` at `index 2`. However, all pages should be built in case user want to see the previous pages as well.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenForBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenForBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenForBuilder> createState() => _ScreenForBuilderState();
}

class _ScreenForBuilderState extends State<ScreenForBuilder> {

  List isCompleted = [];

  apiCallFunction() async {
     isCompleted = ['1','1','0','0'];
    return isCompleted;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: apiCallFunction(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              return PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 4,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('${index+1}', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50),),
                  );
                  }
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `initialPage` in the `PageController`

```
class ScreenForBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenForBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenForBuilder> createState() => _ScreenForBuilderState();
}

class _ScreenForBuilderState extends State<ScreenForBuilder> {
  List isCompleted = [];

  Future<List<String>> apiCallFunction() async {
    List<String> isCompleted = ['1','1','0','0'];
    return isCompleted;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
          future: apiCallFunction(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('something went wrong'),
              );
            }

            final initialPage = snapshot.data!.indexWhere(
              (element) => element == '0',
            );

            return PageView.builder(
              controller: PageController(
                initialPage: initialPage == -1 ? 0 : initialPage,
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${index + 1}',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It shows a blank screen and doesn't move the pages.

Comment: the array was empty, that's why

Comment: Great, I missed it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The code @Hydra provided worked great for me but here is an alternative method. I set the initial page with `indexOf` a flag. Here's my code that also worked.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenForBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenForBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenForBuilder> createState() => _ScreenForBuilderState();
}

class _ScreenForBuilderState extends State<ScreenForBuilder> {

  List isCompleted = [];

  apiCallFunction() async {
    isCompleted = ['1','1','0','0'];
    return isCompleted;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: apiCallFunction(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                return PageView.builder(
                    controller: PageController(initialPage: isCompleted.indexOf('0')),
                    itemCount: isCompleted.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('${index}', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50),),
                      );
                    }
                );
              } else
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```